# How to take user entered data and save it to be later displayed in another view?

Tags: ios, logging, save, transfer

I am very new to the app making world and I am working on a small app that allows users to enter data into text fields and pick a date as well using the integrated interface builder date picker. I have both of these in one view where the user will be able to enter a topic (in the text field) and a date. Now the next step would be to save the data that they enter. The thing is this app is pretty well a log book so people need to be able to go back and see what they entered.

I was wondering if there is anyway to take the data and save it to another another view in a chart format.

Any advice and or ideas are welcome I need all the help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

You can user textFieldDidEndEditing for saving values in NSDictionary and you use those values.

declare NSDictionary, UItextFields in .h file.

```
 NSDictionary *valuesDict = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if(textfield == topicTextfield){
      [valuesDict setValue: textField.text forKey:@"Topic"];
    }else if(textfield == dateTextfield){
      [valuesDict setValue: textField.text forKey:@“Date”];
    }
}
```

You can use valuesDict in any method to access those details

```
NSLog(@"Topic %@", [valuesDict objectForKey:@"topic"]);
NSLog(@"Date %@", [valuesDict objectForKey:@"Date"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many idea for saving, retrieve and sharing data between the controller. In your case if you do not have much data to save and filter then you can forget the solution like sqlite and Core Data and you can save your data into plist file or `NSUserDefault` which can set and get data from any controller within the app.

another thing is for showing data in chart formate i would suggest to use the custom cell with UItableView.